# Python Social Auth get Google avatar

Tags: python, google-plus, google-signin, python-social-auth

Is there a way to get the Google profile picture url using python social auth?

So, this is what I do for facebook and twitter, add a pipeline with this code:

```
    if strategy.backend.name == 'facebook':
        url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture'.format(response['id'])

    elif strategy.backend.name == "twitter":
        if response['profile_image_url'] != '':
            url = response['profile_image_url']

    elif strategy.backend.name == "GoogleOAuth2":  # doesn't work
        user_id = response['id']
        url = "???"
```

First, I don't know what is the name of the backend, is it "GoogleOAuth2"?
Second, what is the url I should use to save the profile's avatar?. Is this the way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from social.backends.google import GoogleOAuth2

def save_profile(backend, user, response, *args, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(backend, GoogleOAuth2):
        if response.get('image') and response['image'].get('url'):
            url = response['image'].get('url')
            ext = url.split('.')[-1]
            user.avatar.save(
               '{0}.{1}'.format('avatar', ext),
               ContentFile(urllib2.urlopen(url).read()),
               save=False
            )
            user.save()
```

Comment: Thanks vero4ka. I didn't want to save the image, only the url so `url_50 = response['image'].get('url')` did the trick. Hope that google doesn't change the url format anytime soon.

Answer (score 2):

To get avatars from social login, you need create a pipeline.py file in your app and add this lines to settings.py:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (

    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
    'apps.users.pipeline.get_avatar', # This is a path of your pipeline.py
    #and get_avatar is the function.
)
```

and later add this content to your pipeline.py file

```
def get_avatar(backend, strategy, details, response,
        user=None, *args, **kwargs):
    url = None
    if backend.name == 'facebook':
        url = "http://graph.facebook.com/%s/picture?type=large"%response['id']
        # if you need a square picture from fb, this line help you
        url = "http://graph.facebook.com/%s/picture?width=150&height=150"%response['id']
    if backend.name == 'twitter':
        url = response.get('profile_image_url', '').replace('_normal','')
    if backend.name == 'google-oauth2':
        url = response['image'].get('url')
        ext = url.split('.')[-1]
    if url:
        user.avatar = url
        user.save()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you don't mind, you should add an explanation to your code. Or comment it at least. You might check [this meta question on code-only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Python Social Auth but it looks like you want [GooglePlusAuth](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/backends/google.html).

To get the image url you will have to make a HTTP request to the [people.get API method](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) with `userId` set to `me` and authenticated as the user. The response includes an `image.url` value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the approach suggested by vero4ka.

Dropping into a python debug (`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`) around the line `ext = url.split('.')[-1]`, I notice that the split output doesn't fully separate the file extension viz:

```
(Pdb) url = response['image'].get('url').split('.')
(Pdb) url
[u'https://lh4', u'googleusercontent', u'com/redacted/redacted/photo', u'jpg?sz=50']
```

I'll need to split off on the `?` symbol too. No big deal.

Not sure why one would split and then recombine the extension in this way?